# Expected depth of quicksort tree

Tags: recurrence-relations, computer-science, expectation, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

It's known that complexity of randomized quicksort algorithm can be estimated as $O(N\log N)$, where $N$ is the length of an array to be sorted. I know two different proofs of this estimation, where we assume that all elements are different, and a pivot is chosen randomly for each step. But these proofs estimate all complexity of the algorithm but not the depth of recursion calls tree. I want to prove that expected depth estimated as $O(\log N)$. This is my plan: let $\xi_N$ be the height of tree (random value), so
$$E\xi_N=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}E\max(\xi_{i-1},\xi_{N-i})+1$$
But I can't compute this. Any ideas

Comment: If you don't get an answer here consider deleting and reposting at https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ . (But don't post in in two places at once.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may prove the estimation $O(k^3)$ for $E(2^{\xi_{k}})$. Then, you can use the Jensen's inequality to show $2^{E(\xi_k)} \leq E(2^{\xi_{k}})$. Taking $log(\cdot)$ of both parts proves the result ([Lecture notes with full details](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-9-relation-of-bsts-to-quicksort-analysis-of-random-bst/lec9.pdf)).